# Updating post meta field not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use the following the code

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://domain.com/forms/3/input', $args );

if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $result = json_decode( $response['body'] );
    update_field( 'dk_id', $result->result->id, $post->ID );
}
```

Somehow the meta is not saved to the database. `$result->result->id` is an `integer` when using `gettype()`.

This code is working for me just fine though:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://domain.com/forms/3/input', $args );

if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $result = json_decode( $response['body'] );
    update_field( 'dk_id', 'TEST', $post->ID );
}
```

It looks like the function won't take my variable. Thanks a bunch for helping out!

Comment: check for errors via PHP and the query.

Comment: For people who are not familiar with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, the update_field() function is very similar to update_post_meta(), using udpate_post_meta() yields the same result for me.

Comment: I checked for errors, but I am not getting any.

Comment: If `$result->result->id` is an integer and you're trying to pass a string a per your other `TEST`. That should be throwing you an error. What's the column's type, `int` or `varchar` or similar? how are you checking for errors exactly?